# sed - find text between 2 strings and use it for replace

Tags: unix, replace, sed, awk

I have a file with many lines like below:

```
townValue.put("Aachen");    
townValue.put("Aalen");             
townValue.put("Ahlen");             
townValue.put("Arnsberg");          
townValue.put("Aschaffenburg");         
townValue.put("Augsburg");
```

I want to change this lines to:

```
townValue.put("Aalen", "Aalen");            
townValue.put("Ahlen", "Ahlen");            
townValue.put("Arnsberg", "Arnsberg");          
townValue.put("Aschaffenburg", "Aschaffenburg");        
townValue.put("Augsburg", "Augsburg");
```

How can I achieve this with sed or awk. This seems to be a special find & replace task, I couldn't find yet in the net.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sed -e 's/"[^"]*"/&, &/'`:

```
$ cat 1
townValue.put("Aachen");    
townValue.put("Aalen");             
townValue.put("Ahlen");             
townValue.put("Arnsberg");          
townValue.put("Aschaffenburg");         
townValue.put("Augsburg");
$ sed -e 's/"[^"]*"/&, &/' 1
townValue.put("Aachen", "Aachen");    
townValue.put("Aalen", "Aalen");             
townValue.put("Ahlen", "Ahlen");             
townValue.put("Arnsberg", "Arnsberg");          
townValue.put("Aschaffenburg", "Aschaffenburg");         
townValue.put("Augsburg", "Augsburg");
```

According to sed(1):

> s/regexp/replacement/
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space. If successful, replace that portion  matched  with  replacement. The replacement may contain the special character **&** to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

Comment: `".*"` is enough for this problem. with `[^"]`, looks better, but if there were really more pairs of `"`, this doesn't work either, it will just replace the first `"..."` who knows if the first is the one OP wants to replace. :)

Answer (score 1):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk),because of the large number of quotes in the command line I recommend to use a script:

```
awk -f script file
```

- script

  ```
  BEGIN {FS=OFS="\""}
  $3=", \""$2"\""$3
  ```

---

```
$ cat file
townValue.put("Aachen");
townValue.put("Aalen");
townValue.put("Ahlen");
townValue.put("Arnsberg");
townValue.put("Aschaffenburg");
townValue.put("Augsburg");

$ awk -f script file
townValue.put("Aachen", "Aachen");
townValue.put("Aalen", "Aalen");
townValue.put("Ahlen", "Ahlen");
townValue.put("Arnsberg", "Arnsberg");
townValue.put("Aschaffenburg", "Aschaffenburg");
townValue.put("Augsburg", "Augsburg");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I get this:`townValue.put("Aachen");          , ""`

Comment: @codyLine this works for me. But there are many double quotes in the command line, it's better to work with a tiny script file here. I made an edit.

Comment: I tried again with the script and here is the result: `~$ awk -F" -v OFS=" -f awk-script townList.txt 
townValue.put("Aachen");          , ""
townValue.put("Aalen");                           , ""
townValue.put("Ahlen");                           , ""
townValue.put("Arnsberg");                        , ""` :-(

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 13.04

Comment: @codyLine I can't test it with Kubuntu. I moved `-F" -v OFS="` inside the script, please check it out. If this doesn't work, please check `awk --version`, current is **4.1.0**

Comment: It works! I tried on my PC with Kubuntu running on it too. Thank u again - nice solution. Would like to explain how the little script works?

Comment: 1) set _field separator_ to double quote makes three fields, $1, $2 and $3. $1 and $2 remain unchanged, $3 = `);`. Now put $2 again before $3, add some double quotes and last the value of $3.